# google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

Tags: ajax, charts, google-visualization

I have google chart on my page, but right now chart is drawn when Google Visualization library is loaded on the page load, and I have to give data dynamically through ajax, so is it possible to change the callback method, or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed with it as i wanted, It can be helpful for someone, and if there is better solution for this please do suggest.

1. I removed this setOnLoadCallback function -  `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`
   This call back will call the drawChart() as soon as the visulization library is loaded,
   (but I didn't wanted it, i wanted to call it on button click).
2. so I called `drawChart();` function directily in the button click function code.
3. Then I faced problem with rendering the dynamic data to the datatable, when I was putting hard coded values, the chart drawn fine, but as I put variables instead of those values, it was unable to generate chart.
4. so i parsed the variable into integer by `parseInt(doc_pre)`,
   And it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this :

[Jquery Charts](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/)

Comment: actually I have already implemented google chart, but with static data, and I want dynamic data should be rendered to chart.